# Pass function to array filter function error - Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, swift4

I'm trying to **extend** the **array class** writing a simple function that will receive a function as parameter and will use that to filter the current array.

In this example "self" is actually an array.

this is what I used so far:

```
    func applyFilter(filterFunction: (String) -> Bool) {
    self.filter(filterFunction)
    }
```

But I'm receiving this error from xCode:

[image: cannot convert value of type '(String) -> BOOL' to expected argument type '_ ' -> Bool]

Any ideas?

Comment: please, provide us with implementation of `filter` function

Comment: I'm extending the array class. So the filter function is the default array function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that, the generic `Array.filter(_:)` function is expecting the `Array.Element` to be passed not a string.

If you change the extension and function to be:

```
extension Array where Element == String {

    func applyFilter(_ filter: (String) -> Bool) {
        self.filter(filter)
    }

}
```

As this specifies that the function will only be dealing with String elements then you can pass a function to the closure as such:

```
func filter(_ value: String) -> Bool { 
    /* Filter how you need */ 
}

["Hello", "World"].applyFilter(filter(_:))
```

Comment: Oh, I was extending the array of a specific type while trying to filter for another type. Thanks a ton man.